# Sql alternative to not exists for a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of sensors and a table for sensor_data. They are both related by common uuid column.

```
**Table sensor:**  
ID    uuid  

**Table B**  
ID    uuid  server_time
```

I need to find count of the sensors that did not give data between a given time frame. For this I am using below query

```
select count(distinct s.uuid) 
from sensor s 
where  not 
  (exists 
    (select 1 from sensor_data d where d.uuid=s.uuid and 
      (d.server_time between ? and ?)
    )
  )
```

Because of the huge size of the table, this query does not perform well. What is a performant alternative to this query?

Comment: I would try formulating it with an EXISTS vs NOT EXISTS (and subtract the result from Sensors' count).

Comment: There is no sensor_data table here.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much you can do to reformulate the query.  What you can do is add an index on `sensor_data(uuid, server_time)` which should help.

In addition, if `uuid` is unique in `sensor`, then just use `count(*)` rather than `count(distinct)`.

Comment: What about this query
select * FROM sensor s left outer join sensor_data d 
on s.uuid=d.uuid and d.server_time between '2020-06-23 13:32:10' and '2021-08-04 13:32:10'
where d.id is null

Comment: @devJoshi . . . It is worth trying but I would expect it to have similar performance characteristics.  It would want the same index.

Comment: Wouldn't EXISTS be more performant than NOT EXISTS?

Comment: @CetinBasoz . . . I don't see how `exists` would answer the question, but you are welcome to provide an answer.